# java cannot resolve imports

Tags: java, import

Some time ago I made a java project for my programming subject, developed in Eclipse. I tested it many times and worked flawlessly. However in the exam's computer didn't, I tried to compile it and returned 16 errors. Now back to my computer I deleted the .class files and compiled again manually returning the same 16 errors. I opened up eclipse to try compile it from within eclipse like the very first time and now shows these errors, I didn't change anything in the code...

Said errors are all the same, missing symbols. The errors are produced when trying to compile one class out of 6 in the package ("Contacto" class). This class uses 4 out of the other 5 classes and there is where the error is produced. One error for each line where one of this 4 classes is used. Eclipse points out the same error and gives a quick fix, importing the missing class, but if I don't remeber badly you don't need to import classes that are located in the same package of the one that are being used at. Anyway I tried importing the suggested class and it produces another error in eclipse (The import 'package name' cannot be resolved) so I don't know what else to try...

The project setup seems fine to me (it even worked once...)

The code is quite simple but quite long also so I will post as few as possible.

```
package fp2.poo.pfpooferdomdel1;

import fp2.poo.utilidades.ContactoInterfaz;
import fp2.poo.utilidades.CorreoElectronicoInterfaz;
import fp2.poo.utilidades.DomicilioInterfaz;
import fp2.poo.utilidades.PersonaInterfaz;
import fp2.poo.utilidades.TelefonoInterfaz;
import fp2.poo.pfpooferdomdel1.CorreoElectronico;  //Tried to import the missing class here, returned error: The import fp2.poo.pfpooferdomdel1.CorreoElectronico cannot be resolved


public class Contacto implements ContactoInterfaz
    {
    CorreoElectronico correo = new CorreoElectronico();  //Error here, missing "CorreoElectronico"
    Domicilio domicilio = new Domicilio();
    Persona persona = new Persona();
    Telefono telefono = new Telefono();
```

The same error goes for the following 3 lines, missing symbols for Domicilio, Persona and Telefono.

One of the errors returned by the console

```
`javac -Xlint -encoding ISO-8859-1 -classpath ./bin  -cp ./bin -d ./bin  ./src/fp2/poo/pfpooferdomdel1/Contacto.java
.\src\fp2\poo\pfpooferdomdel1\Contacto.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
import fp2.poo.pfpooferdomdel1.CorreoElectronico;;
                              ^
  symbol:   class CorreoElectronico
  location: package fp2.poo.pfpooferdomdel1
.\src\fp2\poo\pfpooferdomdel1\Contacto.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        CorreoElectronico correo = new CorreoElectronico();
        ^`
```

Makefile for Contacto.java (it was given by the teachers)

```
     JAVAC=javac
     JAVA=java
     lsJAR=jar
     OPCIONES= -Xlint -encoding ISO-8859-1 -classpath ./bin  -cp ./bin -d ./bin 
    ./bin/fp2/poo/pfpooferdomdel1/Contacto.class: \
                   ./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/TelefonoInterfaz.class \
                   ./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/PersonaInterfaz.class \
                  ./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/DomicilioInterfaz.class \
                   ./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/CorreoElectronicoInterfaz.class \
                   ./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/ContactoInterfaz.class \
                   ./src/fp2/poo/pfpooferdomdel1/Contacto.java
$(JAVAC) $(OPCIONES) ./src/fp2/poo/pfpooferdomdel1/Contacto.java
```

This particular code file is located at ./src/fp2/poo/pfpooferdomdel1/ which I think is consistent with the package name.

Project setup

```
./src/fp2/poo>$ ls
datos  pfpooferdomdel1  principal  utilidades
./src/fp2/poo/pfpooferdomdel1>$ ls
Agenda.java  Contacto.java  CorreoElectronico.java  Domicilio.java  Persona.java  Telefono.java
./src/fp2/poo/principal>$ ls
Principal.java
```

There are more folders and files but I don't think they are relevant.

If anything else is required please do not hesitate to ask it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the CorreoElectronico.java file is missing. It should be in the ./src/fp2/poo/pfpooferdomdel1 directory.

Comment: It is: D:\POO\practica final\pfpoo\src\fp2\poo\pfpooferdomdel1>ls
Agenda.java  Contacto.java  CorreoElectronico.java  Domicilio.java  Persona.java  Telefono.java

Comment: I think all those files have to be listed in the makefile.